# How to load a script without blocking the whole page on Google Chrome?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, firefox, google-chrome

[image]
I am developing a website that uses an Ajax plugin to like/dislike/comments an item. But when there are multiple items on the same page, the page takes too long to be displayed. On google chrome for instance, for 10 items you have to wait something like 10 seconds before you can see anything.

But in Firefox, and IE 8, the other elements of the page are displayed, and only the likes/dislikes take some time. But the advantage is that they are displayed as soon as they are loaded. So this is much better.

So why is Google Chrome less efficient than Firefox and IE?  Is there a trick to display on Chrome the page like in Firefox?

I have attached a Firebug image of the loading page.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try placing your scripts at the bottom of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

See a whole bunch of other tips here

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: Thanks, you responded to a big part of my question. But why does it work on Firefox and not in chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Jason mentioned, dynamically loading scripts is also a very good option. You can insert the `<script>` tag to the `DOM` and then load the `.js` files using JavaScript.